# Adding active class for nav-link with blank request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use following code to make the url nav-link active class when route to 'localhost:3000/home' route :

```
<a class="nav-link {{ (request()->is('home')) ? 'active' : '' }}" href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
```

But change url to 'localhost' route, the similar code is not working:

```
<a class="nav-link {{ (request()->is('')) ? 'active' : '' }}" href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The localhost:3000/ route means / in Laravel. So you use / instead of ''

```
<a class="nav-link {{ (request()->is('/')) ? 'active' : '' }}" href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
```